# Validating arrays using Firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my HTML page I have a group of five checkboxes.  Their values are 1,2,3,4,5.

In the object to which those checkboxes belong I save them as an array.  So if user selects options 2,4,5 I store it as [2,4,5].

I'm stuck at the spot when I try to validate that array in Firebase rules.  Is there any way of doing validation like this?

I want to make sure an array like [5,6,7] does not go through the Firestore rules but something like [1,3,4,5] does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array type fields in Firestore documents show up as [List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) type objects in security rules.  You can use its [hasOnly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasOnly) method to determine if the List contains only certain elements.

```
request.resource.data.arrayField.hasOnly([1,2,3,4,5)
```